# Scala API 2.10.*: Function2.andThen what happened to?

Tags: api, scala, function-composition

I'm reading «Scala in Depth» by Joshua Suereth, book that I've bought for the clearly established competency of the author. I'm on page 3 and after a bunch of typos and incoherent formatting (ok, I've become tolerant of these errors) I stumbled upon the following example about a functional approach to solve a very simple scenario.

```
trait Cat
trait Bird
trait Catch
trait FullTummy

def catch(hunter: Cat, prey: Bird): Cat with Catch
def eat(consumer: Cat with Catch): Cat with FullTummy

val story = (catch _) andThen (eat _)
story(new Cat, new Bird)
```

I took the example with caution provided it's clearly a blue-print (no concrete methods are defined…)… «catch» is clearly another typo provided it's a reserved word… `Cat` and `Bird` are not instantiable…

… but, despite the poor quality of the example, I can't consider that the «story» val defined in terms of function composition (`andThen` is the «reverse-associative» of `compose`) is another accidental mistake provided it's the *core* of the example.

Effectively the example won't compile on my local version of Scala (2.10.1) and it's not documented either on the latest version available (2.10.2).

There is no doubt of its usefulness and that its implementation is easy to accomplish (follow):

```
trait Function2ex[-T1, -T2, +R] extends Function2[T1, T2, R] {
  def andThen[A](g: R => A): (T1, T2) => A = { (x, y) => g(apply(x, y)) }
}
```

After a short scrutiny of the API I found that the `andThen` is supported only by Function1 and supposedly disappeared from Function2 to Function22 so, the question is:

**What is the current idiom to support `andThen` and `compose` with Function* of arity greater than 1?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't understand where that example is going at all, but here's some code that compiles in scala 2.10.2.

```
trait Cat
trait Bird
trait Catch
trait FullTummy

def `catch`(hunter: Cat, prey: Bird): Cat with Catch = ???
def eat(consumer: Cat with Catch): Cat with FullTummy = ???

val story = (`catch` _).tupled andThen (eat _)
story(new Cat with Catch, new Bird {})
```

I had to quote `catch` because it's a reserved word, and tuple the `Function2`.

Comment: can you please elaborate about the tupled. why did you have to use it (I know that it doesn't work otherwise, but why did we have to tuple it, since eat does not accept tuple rather than single parameter "consumer") ? and what is it doing exactly

Comment: We have to tuple it because `(\`catch\` _)` is a `Function2`, which doesn't have an `andThen` method. And the return type (`Cat with Catch`) is what has to match the argument type of `eat`.

Comment: so we actually using the tupled to convert it to Function1 in order to get the "andThen" function, correct ?

Comment: Yes. I'm not really sure why `Function2` doesn't have its own `andThen` method.