# Why doesn't Function2 have an andThen method?

Tags: scala, function-composition

Why does `andThen` only exist for single argument functions in Scala?

The following code works:

```
val double = (x: Int) => x * 2
val timesFour = double andThen double
```

But why is there no `andThen` method for multi argument functions?

```
val multiply = (x: Int, y: Int) => x * y
val multiplyAndDouble = multiply andThen double

<console>:10: error: value andThen is not a member of (Int, Int) => Int
```

Surely it is trivial to add this method. Is there a reason it been omitted from the standard library?

Comment: Related: [How to compose to methods, without duplicate input arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21588082/406435)

Comment: You cannot return more than one 'thing' after executing a function, so how would you do to provide 2 arguments to your function `multiply`?

Comment: You can bridge the gap, as it were, but applying `tupled` to a `FunctionN` (for *N* greater than 1) and get a `Function1` that takes a `TupleN`.

Comment: @vptheron I am talking about the other way around. Apply a `Function2` and then apply the *single* result returned with a `Function1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have just noticed it is easy to work around with the following:

```
val multiplyAndDouble = multiply.tupled andThen double
val res = multiplyAndDouble(1, 3) // res = 6
```

Answer (score 4):

I can't speak as to why `Function2` doesn't supply and `andThen`, but Scalaz defines `Functor` instances for functions of various arities where `map` is equivalent to `andThen`, meaning you could write

```
val multiplyAndDouble = multiply map double
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar question here:
[Scala API 2.10.*: Function2.andThen what happened to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18038321/scala-api-2-10-function2-andthen-what-happened-to), but there is also no answer. In my opinion it is possible. Here is working example for Scala 2.11.1:

```
object TestFunction2 {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val double = (x: Int) => x * 2
    val timesFour = double andThen double
    println(timesFour(2)) // prints 8

    val multiply = (x: Int, y: Int) => x * y
    val multiplyAndDouble = multiply andThen double
    println(multiplyAndDouble(1, 3)) // prints 6
  }

  implicit def toFunc2(function2: Function2[Int, Int, Int]): Func2[Int, Int, Int] = {
    new Func2[Int, Int, Int] {
      def apply(v1: Int, v2: Int): Int = function2(v1, v2)
    }
  }
}

trait Func2[-T1, -T2, +R] extends Function2[T1, T2, R] {
  def andThen[A](g: R => A): (T1, T2) => A = { (x, y) => g(apply(x, y)) }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to write theons's answer is to use:

```
val multiplyAndDouble = double compose multiply.tupled
val result = multiplyAndDouble(2, 6) // res 24
```