# andThen for function of two arguments in Scala

Tags: function, scala

Suppose I have two functions `f` and `g`:

```
val f: (Int, Int) => Int = _ + _
val g: Int => String = _ +  ""
```

Now I would like to compose them with `andThen` to get a function `h`

```
val h: (Int, Int) => String = f andThen g
```

Unfortunately it doesn't compile :(

```
scala> val h = (f andThen g)
<console> error: value andThen is not a member of (Int, Int) => Int
   val h = (f andThen g)
```

Why doesn't it compile and how can I compose `f` and `g` to get `(Int, Int) => String` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't Function2 have an andThen method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21680117/why-doesnt-function2-have-an-andthen-method)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It doesn't compile because `andThen` is a method of `Function1` (a function of one parameter: see the [scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Function1)).

Your function `f` has two parameters, so would be an instance of `Function2` (see the [scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Function2)).

To get it to compile, you need to transform `f` into a function of one parameter, by tupling:

```
scala> val h = f.tupled andThen g
h: (Int, Int) => String = <function1>
```

test:

```
scala> val t = (1,1)
scala> h(t)
res1: String = 2
```

You can also write the call to `h` more simply because of [auto-tupling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997553/why-and-how-is-scala-treating-a-tuple-specially-when-calling-a-one-arg-function), without explicitly creating a tuple (although auto-tupling is a little controversial due to its potential for confusion and loss of type-safety):

```
scala> h(1,1)
res1: String = 2
```

Answer (score 7):

`Function2` does not have an `andThen` method.

You can manually compose them, though:

```
val h: (Int, Int) => String = { (x, y) => g(f(x,y)) }
```