# How to compose curried functions in Scala

Tags: scala, haskell, currying, function-composition

Is it possible compose functions in Scala that are curried? For example:

```
def a(s1: String)(s2: String): Int = s1.length + s2.length
def b(n: Int): Boolean = n % 2 == 0

def x : String => String => Boolean = a andThen b

x("blabla")("foo")
```

Edit :

I've found a way of doing it in Haskell :

```
a :: String -> String -> Int
a s1 s2 = length s1 + length s2

b :: Int -> Bool
b n = mod n 2 == 0

c :: String -> String -> Bool 
c = curry (b . (uncurry a))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala, currying and overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7179229/scala-currying-and-overloading)

Comment: Probably this is the answer you look for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28566214/andthen-for-function-of-two-arguments-in-scala

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but it's not the same question. There's no overloading, and it's not Function2 since it is curried (so Function1 twice, which has andThen).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
def x = a _ andThen (_ andThen b)
```

The first `_` avoids invoking `a` and makes it into a function value. This value is of type `String=>String=>Int`, i.e. a function that takes `String` and returns `String=>Int`.

The argument to the `andThen` method is a function that takes the result of the original function and modifies it. So in this case it requires a function that takes `String=>Int` and returns a new value, a function `String=>Boolean`. We can fabricate this new function by using `andThen` on the original function. This takes the result of `a` and composes it with the new function `b`.